# Lightweight Contact Manager

Tags: windows, contact-manager

I'm looking for lightweight contact manager that I can install on my Windows 8 machine. I'd prefer open source program that can help me sort and search for contacts by varying tags and attributes as well as storing their basic contact info and my notes about them.

I know some of you are thinking google sheets or excel or open office, but I'm not sure if there are any easy ways to give contacts attributes and notes that display easily and are easily searchable.

I want to take detailed notes of interactions with contacts I make so I can remember those interactions better later.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The address book that you are using (probably accessible from your mail program) may go a long way already. Check if it stores all the fixed fields that you need, then look for a plugin that will let you maintain the interactions. And maybe you need a tagging plugin as well, that all depends on what you already have.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jan, one reason I'm looking for a locally installed program is because I'd prefer not to put all my contacts into a service and then have it disappear. Admittedly that's not very likely, but something just feels better about that local instal. I'll take a look for those email plugins though.

Comment: Open Windows Contacts by clicking the Start button, clicking All Programs, and then clicking Windows Contacts.

Comment: Hi Sean, I'm not seeing Windows Contacts anywhere.

Comment: @Fernando There should be a "Contacts" folder in your user directory ("C:\Users\Fernando\Contacts", for example), I think Sean means that, but that might not suit your requirements (I don't think you can set custom tags and attributes, but you might be able to use the "Notes" tab for that)