# Lightweight contact manager for Linux with import & export feature

Tags: linux, offline, csv, contact-manager, vcard

I am looking for a light weight contact manager for Linux (similar to this unanswered request for a [Lightweight Contact Manager](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14541/lightweight-contact-manager) for Windows).

I would like to be able to both import and export vCard files (or possibly CSV files). I would also like to be able to use the contact manager while off line without sharing my data with a 3rd party (e.g., Google).

I currently use [kaddressbook](https://www.kde.org/applications/office/kaddressbook/) and am pretty happy with it, but it seems overkill to install most of KDE for a contact manager (it pulls in over 500 MB of dependencies on my Arch Linux system).

I tried [GFA](http://gfa.sourceforge.net/) and it seems like what I want, except it lacks an import/export feature.

Answer (score 4):

Osmo has been around for years and is pretty good - the GUI's not so flashy, but it's pretty lightweight with minimal dependencies. It has basic import/export functionality, as well as everything you'd expect from a simple address book / contact manager. http://clayo.org/osmo/

You should be able to install it via `sudo aptitude install osmo` on Ubuntu/Debian or `sudo dnf install osmo` on Fedora/CentOS.

Comment: Osmo does not import vcard.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but maybe someone needs an alternative.

See [Evolution](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution). Osmo seems lightweight but it seems not to support vCard so I ended up using Evolution.

It is not as "lightweight" as Osmo what comes to features but it certainly does not need like 500MB libraries related to KDE when using Gnome environment.

For my Linux Mint it was just:

```
apt install evolution
```

Comment: Unfortunately Evolution is incapable of working on address books in abstraction from the notion of "my" address book. I need something that can work with address books / contact lists as standalone documents.

Answer (score 0):

Another option and what I currently use is Thunderbird with [CardBook](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/cardbook/) add-on.

It has the import / export features I need and an extensive collection of preferences that I have not investigated but might be handy.